# Кур - в ощип или во щи?

Tags: фразеология

Просматривала список русских фразеологизмов и нашла вот такое: http://mysubs.ru/o-perevodah/phraseo.html
Интересует конкретно "кур во щи". Насколько я знаю, правильно говорить "попал, как кур в ощип". Щи - это вообще суп без мяса.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, ошибка тут, и или есть и такой вариант поговорки?

Comment: Круто! И, черт побери, как приятно осмыслить логику умных людей!

Comment: Вот тут-то собака и зарыта! Не могли щи с курятины варить, а тут бах тебе - неожиданность, гости у порога. Курица варится по времени меньше чем говядина, быстрее, ее и использовали в крайних и экстренных случаях. Вот кур от неожиданности в щи (вместо супа) и попал!!! Супер! Мне нравится! Согласна полностью с умными людьми 19 века. А в "ощип" - пожалуй, не столь актуально.

Comment: Я, конечно, не кулинар, но разве курица, прежде чем попасть во щи, не ощипывается? Разве может она попасть во щи, предварительно не попав в ощип?

Answer (score 5):

Если говорить о происхождении выражения, то тут разные версии и "кур в ощип" одна из многих, причём вряд ли верная (что такого необычного в том, что петуха съели, чтобы для поговорки использовать?), но написания и произношения фразеологизма это не меняет - **попасть как кур ВО ЩИ**.

Данное выражение зафиксировано в письменной речи с XVII века и с самого начала писалось "кур во щи", так что именно в таком виде оно и зафиксировано почти во всех фразеологических словарях, в том числе и в том, что по ссылке.

Основных версий происхождения поговорки три:
 1. Кур во щи. Петух попал в суп, который обычно не делают на курином бульоне, но по случаю неожиданных гостей вполне могли быть.
 2. Кур во щип. Птица из семейства куриных попала в щип (ловушку).
 3. Кур в ощип. Петуха съели, как я уже писал, версия меньше всего сочетается со смыслом выражения.

Comment: Божежь, Марк Из, а Вы как смысл поговорки понимаете, что считаете его несочетаемым с версией? По мне так - в десятку. Вот "во щи" - это по смыслу действительно несколько за уши притянуто. 

>и с самого начала писалось "кур во щи",  
 
Впервые слышу. А с этим куром разбираюсь уже почитай лет тридцать.

>но по случаю неожиданных гостей вполне могли б.  
  
Не могли б. Тогда б это бы ли бы не щи. А юшка или уха. 
Помимо всего прочего, щи - исходно это что-то кислое или подкисленное, с куриным жиром не здорово сочетается. Это уже относительно современное "творчество".

Comment: @behemothus, поговорка о человеке неожиданно попавшем в неприятное, неловкое положение. Ощип кура, который ни для каких целей кроме еды не годен, явление явно не неожиданное.

>Впервые слышу. А с этим куром разбираюсь уже почитай лет тридцать

Самая старая запись поговорки сохранилась в хрониках XVII века о Лжедмитрии; она известна в немецко-латинском и русском лексиконе 1731 года. Везде, если не учитывать орфографию, **щи**.

>Не могли б. Тогда б это бы ли бы не щи

"куря во штяхъ" одно из блюд в  "Росписи царским кушаньям" 1610 года.

Comment: >Ощип кура, который ни для каких целей кроме еды не годен, явление явно не неожиданное.  
  
"Неожиданное" - ваша фантазия. Речь идет о безвыходном, крайне неприятном положении. Петуха начали ощипывать. Он может, еще жив, но перспектива очевидная.

>"куря во штяхъ" одно из блюд в "Росписи царским кушаньям" 1610 года.   
  
И как вы это переводите?
А, это Мокиенко... Не, не пойдет. Хотелось бы первоисточник ждля подобного заявления..

Answer (score 1):

Мне сдается, что пословица изначально звучала вот так : **попал, как кур ваще!**))) То есть ни за что попал в переделку, ведь курей не "за что-то" в суп кладут, а "для чего"...
*Ты виноват уж в том, что хочется мне кушать!*
П.С. Мой ответ, разумеется, пятнично-шутливый...

А вот и серьезный суботний разбор)
Статья в САР 1789-94 :

> **Щи**, щей, сущ., ж. род, множ.
> **Варево съ говядиною, рыбою** и рубленою капустою или другой какой молодой зеленью приправленные...
> *Пустые щи.* Щи съ одною капустою и крупою вареные.

В Словаре 1847 то же самое написано : *с говядиною*. 
Словарь Михельсона из 19 столетия сообщает нам :

> **как кур во щи** 
> (попал) — неожиданно в беду
> (Он) на торгах раз так зарвался,
> Что словно во щи кур попался!
> Н. Макаров. Метаморфозы.
> Шел он, шел, да и напоролся сам на свою беду, и попал, как кур во щи: так-таки его и взяли черкесы живьем руками — на ловца и зверь бежит, а он сам сердечный на них и набежал.
> В.И. Даль. Где потеряешь, не знаешь.
> По М. Беру — "как кур во щи" говорилось о Дмитрии Самозванце.
> См. **попался как ворона в суп**.

Наверное, куры были несколько дезориентированы *варевом с говядиною и рыбой*; не ожидая подвоха, спокойно клевали пшено (помните Жар-птицу?) и попадались вместо вышеозначенных животно-рыбных ингридиентов в супец.

Воскресное дополнение.
Слова *ощип(ъ)* не фиксирует ни один словарь русского языка. Оно встречается исключительно в литературных текстах последних ста с небольшим лет, в составе переосмысленной кем-то поговорки. Возвращаясь к своему пятнично-шутливому предположению (**ваще**), я вспомнил древнерусское наречие **вотще** :

> **ВЪТЪЩЕ** (39) нар. Напрасно:
>
> ничьсо же бл҃го вътъще творити. УСт XII/XIII, 220; имать на пожданиѥ и дрѹгыи м(с)ць. аще же и дрɤгыи м(с)ць **преиде вътъще…** {прошел напрасно} да бѹдеть ѿлѹченъ КР 1284, 110г; вотще и въсѹѥ трѹдихсѩ. ни во что же бы(с) трѹдъ мои. ПНЧ 1296, 54; тьмь вътъще молѩ (διακενῆς) Там же, 148; аще ли не тьрпиши ѹкоризны. то вътще гл҃ши. Пр 1383, 92а; и будеть вотще крѣпость ваша (εἰς κενόν) ПНЧ XIV, 113а; вотще оскорбиши д҃шю водѹ ѿ жажа приходѩщю погрети ѿ тебе. Там же, 204г; да не вотще трудъ вашь ˫авить(с). (εἰς κενόν) ФСт XIV, 29г; и ѿиметь ˫а бурѩ мо˫а труды. да вотще тружюсѩ. (εἰς κενόν) ГБ XIV, 100а; Иѡнино пр҃рч(с)тво вотще бы(с). СВл XIII сп. к. XIV, 6; вътъще ка˫ати(с) СбСоф к. XIV, 111г; тѣм же не вотще бы(с) поспѣшенье и(х). (εἰς μάτην) ЖВИ XIV–XV, 125в.

*Попал как кур вотще* ~~~ ни за что попал в переделку, напрасно.
А вообще-то я склоняюсь к мысли, что широкие народные массы на протяжении столетий русской истории могли по-разному воспринимать и понимать это выражение. Но смысл его всегда был примерно одинаков : человек очутился в неприятном и опасном положении.

Решающее соображение в пользу **щей**. *Ощип* для кура/курицы **абсолютно не страшен**, ибо они его уже не чувствуют. Сначала все-таки птицу забивают путем отрубания головы или иным способом, спускают кровь, затем ошпаривают кипятком, а уж потом... потом ощипывают перышки. Ощип не страшен куру, вот ни чуточки)))

*Попасть как кур во щи* - иносказание, фигура речи. Значение поговорки :  *быть съеденным* своими врагами, потерпеть полный урон.

Comment: А форму "курей" тоже по пятницам употребляете? )))

Comment: >Уж оченно много нониче смешных людей развелось, ваше превосходительство!

Comment: Как-то  сомневаюсь,  что  процесс  ощипывания  птицы  не  могли  называть  ощипом  и  более  ста  лет  назад.  Если  есть  глагол  ощипывать,  то  почему  бы  не  быть  отглагольному  существительному  "ощип".

Comment: Все дело в том, что вплоть до конца 19 века употреблялся **единственный** вариант (*во щи*), обратного **никто не доказал**. Что было первым, то и является исходным. 
>Т. Г. Шевченко. Художник (1856)  
А твой-то великодушный дурак и **бух, как кур во щи.** 

Согласитесь, *бухнуться* можно в суп, но не в *ощипывание*. Первый пример *ощипа* :  
>Валентин Курицын. Томские трущобы (1906)  
― внутренне бесился черкес, проклиная свою неосторожность, ― как кур в ощип влопался!

Валентину Курицыну пришелся по душе новый вариант, с него и пошло...

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к двум приведенным в вопросе вариантам.
В последнее время я уже несколько раз слышал в неформальных беседах вариант "Попал, как курвощип" в шуточном значении "внезапно раскрылись его непристойные похождения" (см. [курва](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0)).
Разумеется, это не более чем шуточно-сленговый вариант, но для собирателей подобного фольклора он может быть также интересен.