# о пословице "попасть, как кур во щи"

Tags: значение-слов

Недавно просмотрел трактовку пословицы «попасть, как кур во щи». Во всех вариантах и в комментариях сводится к курице или петуху. Если бы так, то был бы аналог поговорки «индюк думал, пока в суп попал». Думаю, в этой поговорке другой смысл. В ней Кур – древнерусское чудовище, которое встречается в восточных и русских сказках. Вот он-то и попал в кипяток, как волк в сказке про трёх поросят. В комментариях дописать не смог. Пишу здесь.

Comment: Вопрос на эту тему уже рассматривался https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/31117/Кур-в-ощип-или-во-щи